# PropelException: Unable to execute UPDATE statement ... [wrapped: Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column: ...]

Tags: symfony1

I have an odd problem with propel in symfony. I've found a few similar questions here but none of the answers was helpful unfortunately.

So, I've added a new attribute into a db table, changed the schema and regenerated the model classes, and now when I try to save the form it shows an error message: "PropelException: Unable to execute UPDATE statement ... [wrapped: Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column: ...]"

The new field is for sure in the schema.yml file, it actually has been generated using "symfony propel:build-schema" and there should be no problem. I also checked the code of the Base model files and the Table files and the new field is there too. It goes without saying that I did clear the cache. I also tried using different names for that field with no luck.

What can be causing it? What is ColumnMap and where can I see it?

Comment: what is the name of this column?

Comment: Also please specify which version of Symfony and Propel do you use. It would be nice to see full description of the table in schema.yml

Comment: The versions are: symfony 1.4.10 and propel 1.5.3

Comment: The name doesn't seem to be a problem. I even tried "test" and no luck anyway.

Comment: Check for few things: 1. SF application connects to a proper database with updated table 2. Corresponding Peer class contains correct name of the table and new field

Comment: Yes, I already checked this. An important detail is that the get method works for this field. So, e.g. $model->getTest() works but $model->setTest() doesn't.

Comment: Were files in `lib/models/map` updated?

Comment: Yes, in the related TableMap file I see "$this->addColumn('TEST', 'Test', 'VARCHAR', true, 45, null);"